# How to resolve LOAD DATA INFILE issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion

When I try to use this sql statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'url/file.txt'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE myTbl
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(SPEC, PERSON, BLAH, BLUH)
```

I get this error: **Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.**  I am trying to insert into an access database.  Any clues as to how I can get this LOAD DATA INFILE to work?

the same error also occurs with my BULK INSERT attempts

Comment: As mentioned in your other thread that is a MySQL-specific command. You cannot use it in MS Access.

Comment: You are going to need a schema.ini file to load a file with non-standard delimiters into Access using SQL, I reckon.

Comment: @Remou - That is what I thought. What delimiters does Access consider standard: commas and tabs?

Comment: Just fixed width and csv, I am afraid for import with ACE/Jet and SQL, unless you have a schema.ini. In Access itself, there are a lot more options.

Comment: @Remou - Ah, okay. I was thinking tab-delim was standard too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As already mentioned in the comments, that is an MySQL-specific command. So MS Access will not understand it.)

MS Access is a desktop database. So its tools are not as robust as with enterprise databases. It does support dynamic reading of csv files using `IN external database`. But I believe that only works with .csv (and possibly tab delimited) files. For other formats you would need to use a [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx) file.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/select-statement-HP001032265.aspx

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable ( Columns )
SELECT  Columns...
FROM    tableexpression [, ...] [IN externaldatabase]
```

Aside from doing an INSERT the long way (row by row), that is the only option I know of for MS Access.

Answer (score 2):

Load Data infile is a mysql-only sql command,
for ms access db you can use vpa to import text file into table

Take a look here :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113905

Answer (score 1):

Those are commands for MySQL. You cannot use them in access.